# I want to fetch Azure SQL table data from ADF to use as input in copy activity

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have 4 SQL tables.

1. Employee(which contains employee information)
2. Engineers( same structure as EMployee but no input)

3)Student( same structure as EMployee but no input)

4)Metadata ( contains the source and destination information such as source: Employee destination: Student)

My goal is to create an ADF pipeline that will fetch metadata table information (source and destination) and will perform copy activity from the source to destination as per data in the Metadata table.

**Employee Table**

[image]

**Metadata Table**

[image: Flag Source destination 2 dbo.Employee dbo.Engineer]

**Engineer Table**

[image: ID First_name Last_name]

I want my ADF pipeline to fetch the source and destination data from Metadata table and perform copy activity from source to destination as per mentioned in Metadata table.

I have tried the below approaches but not succeeded yet.

getMetadata---> copyActivity [ not able to fetch the metadata table data]

getmetadata--->foreach loop----> copy activity [ again for able to fetch the data]

Comment: Please show use theses table schema and the output data which your expect.

Comment: Edited now. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Amrita Ghatak, You're welcome. Please see my answer. If you have any other concern please feel free to let me know, thank you.

Comment: Does flag indicate which ID to copy or do you copy the entire table?  In @LeonYue answer this will copy entire table and insert all rows to the destination - if your id is PK this will fail on any subsequent runs with the same table

Comment: @JasonWelch, I just made a example. You could build a query according the foreach item in source query operation to get the data you want.

Comment: @JasonWelch Flag indicates which type of copy it should perform. if 1 then blob to blob and if 2 then SQL to SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Lookup active not Get Metadata active.

According you problem,, please follow this workaround:

1. Using [Lookup active](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) to get the content of the table `Metadata`.
   [image]
2. For each active to loop the each row of `Metadata`:
   [image]
3. Foreach inner actives, create the copy active which source and sink
   all set with foreach item. For example:
   [image]
   [image]

HTH.

Comment: Can you please tell me how you selected 'destination properties' source and destination in copy data activity? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AmritaGhatak please set dataset parameter, then you could see the properties in source and sink.

Comment: Hi @AmritaGhatak, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. If you still have any other concerns, please feel free to let me know. Thank you.